# Multi-user Datasources - Spring + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, multi-tenant

I'm writing a web app that supports multiple users. Each user has their own database - using H2. all database schemas are the same.

I wish to use Spring + Hibernate for this application.

So I'm stuck at how to associate a user's database with that user - maybe associated it in the HTTPSession, and extend spring's AbstractRoutingDataSource? but wouldn't this effect Hibernate's cache? Another way is to have a SessionFactory with each datasource, even though every datasource's schema is the same... so I see that as a waste.

Anyways selecting the datasource needs to be dynamic - they can't be pre-configured in context files, as each new user will have its own database created. Is there any existing frameworks/solutions?

I don't know too much about Hibernate Shards, maybe that works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *might* be wrong about the (strict) need to have one `SessionFactory` per database, as suggested by some resources:

[Dynamic DataSource Routing](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

I'll take some time to re-read everything tomorrow (I didn't get all the details to be honest) and to fully understand the implications of such a setup (although it seems clear that it will break the second-level cache). I'll come back on this later.

---

> I'm writing a web app that supports multiple users. Each user has their own database - using H2. all database schemas are the same.

I wonder how this will scale... How many users do you have? How do you run H2, what mode?

> So I'm stuck at how to associate a user's database with that user - maybe associated it in the HTTPSession, and extend spring's AbstractRoutingDataSource?

You'll have to build a `SessionFactory` per user and associate it to the logged user (in a `Map`, using the login as key) and then obtain a `Session` from a given `SessionFactory`. Binding the lifecycle of the `SessionFactory` to the HTTP session seems to be a good idea (to save some memory) but I am not sure Spring will be very helpful here. I might be wrong but a  variation of the `HibernateUtil` class and a fully programmatic approach looks easier. I'm not sure you'll need multiple connections per user by the way.

> but wouldn't this effect Hibernate's cache?

What cache?

> Another way is to have a SessionFactory with each datasource, even though every datasource's schema is the same... so I see that as a waste.

Oh, it's a waste, but that's what you want to do (one database per user). And you don't have the choice (you need one `SessionFactory` per datadabase). Why do you need one database per user actually? Are you sure this is a wise decision? As already hinted, this means much troubles, won't scale well, adds complexity, etc. Why not using a single database and associating data to the user?

> Anyways selecting the datasource needs to be dynamic - they can't be pre-configured in context files, as each new user will have its own database created. Is there any existing frameworks/solutions?

Not to my knowledge. Which is also why I think you'll have to do everything programatically.

> I don't know too much about Hibernate Shards, maybe that works?

Given the dynamic needs of your application, I don't see how it could help.

Comment: Hi Pascal, Thanks for your reply.

All the databases have the same schema, so one SessionFactory for all these databases would be fine.
Hibernate has a 2nd level cache, which might contain invalid cached data if I load 2 unique entities from 2 different databases but with the same IDs.
I think I can get this to work by associating the DataSource with a HttpSession, and using an Interceptor to attach the DataSource in the HttpSession to ThreadLocal so that my AbstractDataSource impl can get the correct DS for the transaction.

Comment: +1 for the Ken DeLong article -- it saved me a few headaches :-)

Answer (score 3):

This may help you:

- [Dynamic Datasource via Spring using HotSwappableTargetSource](http://affy.blogspot.com/2007/11/dynamic-datasource-via-spring-using.html)
- [Hibernate + Spring using multiple datasources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860918/hibernate-spring-using-multiple-datasources)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help from the 2 people (Pascal and org.life.java)!

It is possible, but with some problems: e.g. the hibernate 2nd level cache/query cache.

This link supplied by Pascal is a very good resource:

http://www.jroller.com/kenwdelong/entry/horizontal_database_partitioning_with_spring.

My main motivation for giving each user a separate database is because the data is likely to grow rapidly, thus horizontal partitioning is required.